# Cannot specify a non default C/C++ compiler in CMake under MinGW64 / MSYS

Tags: gcc, cmake, development-environment, mingw-w64

From Mingw-w64, CMake cannot find the non-default compiler I specified on the command line.

This is the pre-build output:

```
MINGW64 /C/projects/TEST
$ cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/mingw64/bin/gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/mingw64/bin/g++ ../Test-LineHandler
Sub-project name: Test
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/projects/TEST/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

However, both `gcc` and `g++` exist:

```
$ ls -l C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 RFT RFT 2218766 Dec 10 00:50 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc

$ ls -l C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++
-rwxr-xr-x 1 RFT RFT 2221326 Dec 10 00:50 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++

$ ls -l /mingw64/bin/gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 RFT RFT 2218766 Dec 10 00:50 /mingw64/bin/gcc

$ ls -l /mingw64/bin/g++
-rwxr-xr-x 1 RFT RFT 2221326 Dec 10 00:50 /mingw64/bin/g++
```

This is the generated `CMakeOutput.log` file:

```
$ more ./CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
The system is: Windows - 10.0.19041 - AMD64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/projects/TEST/CMakeFiles/3.19.3/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/projects/TEST/CMakeFiles/3.19.3/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"
```

Am I specifying the non default compiler correctly on the command line?

Comment: Have you checked the log `C:/projects/TEST/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log` as the error message suggests? The log could contain compiler invocations and resulting error messages.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Strange, from the `CMakeOutput.log` file, it looks like GCC is picked correctly (see extended question).

Comment: Have you tried adding the `.exe` extension, so the full path to the compiler is the actual full path.
You could also try the full Windows path to the compiler, but as that contains backslashes you would need to enclose it in single quotes in MSYS shell.

Comment: @BrechtSanders - Yes, it works adding the `.exe` extension. If you rewrite it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact error is: `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.`

Which is correct as the full path is `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe`.

So just include the `.exe` extension of the compiler specified.

Comment: We are still on Windows, after all ;-)